# Trying to navigate to page location when selecting option from select options dropdown

Tags: javascript

so I have a select box like this with more elements being loaded in of course.

```
<select class="cherry-dropdown">
   <option class="cherryOption" value="#cherry_'.$rownum.'">'.$name.'</option>
</select>
```

And. I'm trying to use javascript to take me to the appropriate page location based off the value attribute in the option.

```
$('.cherry-dropdown').click(function(){
   console.log("yes");

   $('.cherryOption').click(function(){
      console.log("maybe");
      window.location=$(this).val();
   });
});
```

I'm getting yes from the first console.log (opening the select box to reveal the options). But when I click an option I'm not getting the maybe console.log, and thus the window.location part isn't working as well.

What am I doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only actually need one event listener here, if you target the select menu itself (.cherry-dropdown) and listen for a `change` event instead of `click`, and then by passing the event as a argument to access it's value.

```
$(".cherry-dropdown").change(function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.value); //Returns the selected options value
    window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: I really only want the cherryOption event, I tried to put it inside the other one because I'm able to get data from the <select but when I click on the <option Im not getting any results. I did remove it like you have shown above but I still am only getting the console.log from the cherry-dropdown

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully see the question for what it was, I updated my answer with what should help